# May someone explain the following os.fork() example to me?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

[Code taken from Programming Python 4th Edition by Mark Lutz]

```
"forks child processes until you type 'q'"
import os
def child():
    print('Hello from child', os.getpid())
    os._exit(0) # else goes back to parent loop

def parent():
    while True:
        newpid = os.fork()
        if newpid == 0:
            child()
        else:
            print('Hello from parent', os.getpid(), newpid)
        if input() == 'q': break

parent()
```

What the code outputs when ran:

```
Hello from parent 2057 2062 
Hello from child 2062

Hello from parent 2057 2068 
Hello from child 2068

Hello from parent 2057 2069 
Hello from child 2069

Hello from parent 2057 2070 
Hello from child 2070 
q
```

Things I understand:

1. `os.fork()` is used to start another process in parallel to the current one.
2. `os.fork()` creates a copy of the previous Python session and opens it in parallel.
3. `os.fork()` returns the id of the new process.

Things I don't understand:

1. How come the value of `os.getpid()` is never changed when the code runs?
2. Why is the `child()` function ever called? Let's say that the value of `newpid` != 0, then the program will print out `print('Hello from parent', os.getpid(), newpid)`. However, after that, it prints the line from child rather than asking for an input as the case is after the if statement.
3. What is `os._exit(0)` doing?

Thanks a ton for your time. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1: How come the value of os.getpid() is never changed when the code runs?

The value of `os.getpid()` will never change for the parent since that's always the same process. The pid will change every time for the child since `fork()` always creates a brand new child process clone with its own PID.

> 2: Why is the child() function ever called? Let's say that the value of newpid != 0, then the program will print out print('Hello from parent', os.getpid(), newpid). However, after that, it prints the line from child rather than asking for an input as the case is after the if statement.

The child process is called because there are now two processes running. One called the `child()` function, the other called the `print` function. They are simply fighting for printing to the screen, and you saw the parent print "win" first in this case.

> 3: What is os._exit(0) doing?

See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit

> Exit the process with status n, without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc.

Comment: So, isn't the line `newpid = os.fork()` being run on the same process (`parent()`)?

Comment: Updated my answer - yes os.fork is run on the same process as the parent.

Comment: Okay, so I got the child part, however, my question stays the same: `newpid = os.fork()` is being run on the same process as `os.fork()` of `print('Hello from parent', os.getpid(), newpid)`. Then why is `newpid` showing different values?

Comment: `newpid = os.fork()` before this line there is one process. After this line there are two processes that are exactly the same EXCEPT: `newpid` will be 0 for the child process, and `newpid` will be the child's pid in the parent process. The never changing value you see after "hello from parent" is the parent id. It's the value after that the is the childs PID (and that one is changing)

Answer (score 3):

1. Because your parent process has always the same pid  as long as it runs (`while True:`).
2. The child is actually a copy of the parent. That's what `os.fork` does! And the function returns the pid of the child to the parent. So the parent runs the second part of the `if else`-statement, while all childs run the first part, because `os.fork` for child processes gives a 0 back.
3. `os._exit` is essentially a stripped down version of `os.exit()`, and is meant for child processes.

Comment: Then why is `newpid` showing different values? Isn't that being run in the same process as well?